# IPython %logstart logging with output from pydev

Tags: python, logging, pydev, ipython

I use PyDev with IPython console and would like to automatically login my session together with output.

```
from datetime import datetime
curD = str(datetime.today())
currentDate = curD[8:10] + curD[5:7] + curD[2:4] + curD[11:13] + curD[14:16]
logFileName = '~/logs/log_' + currentDate + '.py'
```

After Ctrl+Alt+Enter I need to type `%logstart` and paste string from my `logFileName`. Although it is not bad (1) I would like to log an output from the console in my file. I try to use

```
logstart -o
WARNING: Couldn't start log: Log file is already active: ~/logs/log_2309121715.py
```

When I type `__IP.logger.log_output = True` it does not change logging behaviour.

(2) I also would like to do that automatically so whenever I run PyDev it opens IPython and logs to the file by default. Is it possible to write code to call in my script to perform it?

Comment: you could pack everything in a bash script / shell script and run this each time I suppose, or use P/Open and run the process from ipython...

Comment: But how does it correspond to PyDev and logging console from PyDev session?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it'll do what you want, but you may configure the initial commands that PyDev sends when creating a shell in:

window > preferences > pydev > interactive consoe > initial interpreter commands.